# Tmux and GPM on bare tty

Tags: tmux, gpm

I am running Tmux 2.2 on Arch Linux. I tend to use it from a raw TTY console, rather than an xterm in a window manager. I have GPM installed and running, however I cannot seem to get GPM and Tmux to work together at all.

I've enabled the mouse functions with `setw -g mouse on` however, none of the operations actually function. Selecting a panel/window doesn't work; and I cannot use the mouse in mouse-enabled applications running in Tmux, such as MidnightCommander. MC works with the mouse outside of Tmux, but not inside.

Is there a way to get GPM and Tmux to get along? Or does tmux rely on X11 to handle the mouse interaction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried other apps inside tmux besides MC? I had some odd experiences myself with mc/tmux together which were working fine with mc only.

Comment: @schaiba Yeah, vim is the other one I primarily use; mouse actions do not get passed to it either, even when vim is set with `mouse=a`

Comment: afaik tmux doesn't rely on X to handle mouse interactions, that's what gpm is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short: no.

Long: it does not work because gpm and tmux make conflicting interpretations about the `TERM` environment variable.

- gpm checks if `TERM` begins with `"xterm"`, and if so does nothing more in [`Gpm_Open`](https://github.com/telmich/gpm/blob/master/src/lib/liblow.c#L190) than return a file descriptor.  This is done for *clients* (the gpm *server* works as designed).
- the Linux console [reportedly](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) provides for an application initializing it and enabling a subset of xterm-style mouse controls.  gpm will not do this, because it checks `TERM`.
- tmux could (somehow) determine that it is really talking to gpm on Linux console, but that isn't done (too specialized).

Comment: Not even with some creative environment var manipulation? I presume not...

Comment: No - reading the code and a quick check with vttest in tmux, what I see is that the application (tmux) would have to fill in the initialization parts that gpm might have done rather than simply returning a file descriptor.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate you looking so deep into this :) Thanks!

Comment: no problem (it's related to [one of my FAQs](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#using_gpm_lib))